# Error building native image with GraalVM native-image-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm creating a native image for a JavaFX application using native-image-maven-plugin with GraalVm 21.0.0.2. When I try to execute it after the build end successfully I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.class$(Unknown Source) 
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findClassLoader(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: If you have a JavaFX project, check the Gluon client plugin https://docs.gluonhq.com, https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Jose Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) comment I was able to build the native image using the Gluon plugin. I used the [gluon plugin samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples). But firs I needed to bump my code to parse XML using Stax instead of Sax: [parse XML in java](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html).